# How to pass the notifications number to views?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to **display the number of new notifications** as it is shown on the picture below.

[image]

As you understand, to display this number, it is required for **every action** to pass `$notificationsNumber` to **every view**. Is there a way to do this other than to add this functionality to every action separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a view composer: https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers

Yours might look something like this:

```php
public function __construct(NotificationsRepository $notifications)
{
    // Dependencies automatically resolved by service container...
    $this->notifications = $notifications;
}

public function compose(View $view)
{
    $view->with('notificationsNumber', $this->notifications()->where('read',false)->get()->count());
}
```

Then you include it in a service provider and tie it to your `menu` view.  Laravel will run it and add `$notificationsNumber` anytime the `menu` view is rendered